# Tutorial OpenCl event handling

Tags: event-handling, opencl

In my last question, [OpenCl cleanup causes segfault.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3727534/opencl-cleanup-causes-segfault) , somebody hinted that missing event handling, i.e. not waiting for code to finish, could cause the seg faults. Since then I looked again into the tutorials I used, but they don't pay attention to events ([Matrix Multiplication 1 (OpenCL)](http://gpgpu-computing4.blogspot.com/2009/09/matrix-multiplication-1.html) and `NVIDIA_OpenCL_GettingStartedLinux.pdf`) or talk about it in detail and (for me) understandable.

Do you know a tutorial on `where and how to wait` in OpenCL?

Merci!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't have a tutorial on events in OpenCL, and I'm by no means an expert, but since no one else is responding...

As a rule of thumb, you'll need to wait for any function named `clEnqueue*`. Those functions return immediately before the job is done. The easiest way to make sure your queue is finished is to call `clFinish()`. It won't return until the entire queue has completed.

If you want to get a little fancier, most of the `clEnqueue*` functions have an optional `cl_event` parameter that you can pass in. You can check on a particular event with `clGetEventInfo()`, and you can wait for a particular set of events to finish with `clWaitForEvents()`.